# good way to extract nodejs url

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, url

I wanted to know if there is a way to extract a url like

```
http://whatever:3000/somemethod/val1/val2/val3
```

If there any way to do this instead of using a .split after getting the path name?

Like, I tried to get /somemethod/val1/val2/val3 and then i wanted to split and get somemethod, val1, val2 and val3.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: require("url").parse(strUrl)

Comment: If `location.pathname.split('/')` gives you what you want, I don't see why that's a bad solution.

Comment: If it just is about getting the different Path-Segements out from an URL-String, i think splitting by `/` is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this kind of mapping, a MVC solution  ss best suited for you. Try [Express](http://expressjs.com/) for instance.

**Updated:** 
Example of route mapping with express:

```
app.get('/somemethod/:val1/:val2/:val3', function(val1,val2,val3){
  // ... 
})
```

Comment: Updated the answer with a example of route mapping with arguments.